# Quiero hacer un botón que cada vez que lo presiones sume +1

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="document.getElementById('mostrador').value=parseInt(document.getElementById('mostrador').value+0)+1)" />
```

Quiero hacer un botón que cada vez que lo presione sume `+1`. Por ejemplo, al presionarlo la primera vez da `1`, la segunda vez da `2`, la tercera da `3` y así sucesivamente.

Solo he logrado concatenar un `1` tras otro. Sé que hay una forma de hacerlo con `parseInt`, pero no la encuentro.

Comment: Hola @yehosua, ¿quieres concatenar secuencialmente?, por ejemplo, `1234567...` o ¿simplemente, incrementar de 1 en 1 el valor sin concatenar?

Comment: En efecto, quiero incrementar el valor  de 1 en 1 sin  concaquetenar

Comment: Ok, dale. Te enviaré una respuesta sobre cómo realizarlo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contenedor">
            <div class="contador">0</div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">aumentar</button>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="hola.js"></script>
</html>
```

hola.js

```
let btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
let div1 = document.querySelector(".contador");
let sumar = 1;

document.querySelector(".contador").innerText = 0;

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    div1.innerText = parseInt(div1.innerText) + sumar;
});
```

codigo de ejemplo: https://codepen.io/matimagallanes/pen/gOLOOpR

Answer (score 6):

> Por favor, considere leer toda la explicación, porque es la parte más importante de esta publicación. Puede revisar y probar inmediantamente el código, pero se recomienda seguir la recomendación de este párrafo.

### Incrementación numérica de 1 en 1

Como buena práctica, se recomienda sustituir la siguiente línea:

```html
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="document.getElementById('mostrador').value=parseInt(document.getElementById('mostrador').value+0)+1)" />
```

Por esta otra:

```html
<button id="boton">+</button>
```

Porque se hace mucho más fácil de mantener.

> En esta publicación voy a colocar dos soluciones. Una más fácil que la otra, es decir, una sin ningún tipo de validación y otra con validaciones.

#### Primera solución

Esta es la más fácil y la que **no cuenta con validaciones.** Consiste en crear una variable al que le incrementaremos su valor numérico cada vez que presionemos el botón <kbd>+</kbd>, colocando su valor actualizado a la caja de texto:

```js
let numero = 0;
boton.onclick = () => {
 numero++;
 mostrador.value = numero;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mostrador">
<button id="boton">+</button>
```

En la línea:

```js
numero++;
```

La variable `numero` incrementará su valor de 1 en 1 por cada clic que reciba el botón, mientras que:

```js
mostrador.value = numero;
```

Recibirá el valor actualizado de `numero` .

#### Segunda solución

Esta es un poco más compleja, a la vez, que es más eficiente que la anterior, porque incluye algún tipo de validación y toma un valor existente de la caja de texto si lo hay:

```js
boton.onclick = () => {
  let numero = Number(mostrador.value.trim(" "));
  numero = !isNaN( numero ) ? numero + 1 : 1;

  mostrador.value = numero;
}
```

```css
:root {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif, arial;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
```

```html
<p>Pruebe presionando el botón con la caja de texto vacía, luego le colocas cualquier número y finalmente, prueba colocando caracteres:</p>

<hr>

<input type="text" id="mostrador">
<button id="boton">+</button>
```

> **Nota,** no tome en cuenta como una solución el **código CSS** para este ejemplo. Solamente, considere la **estructura HTML** que forman la caja de texto y el código **JavaScript**.

**Explicación**

En la siguiente línea:

```js
let numero = Number( mostrador.value.trim(" ") );
```

Se declara la variable `numero` , mientras que `Number` es el objeto que devuelve un valor primitivo a partir del valor obtenido de la caja de texto **mostrador**, es decir, `mostrador.value.trim(" ")` y el método `trim(" ")` nos permite eliminar los espacio sobrantes.

Si el objeto **Number** devuelve **NaN** es porque el valor obtenido de la caja de texto no es numérico y por lo tanto, esto nos lleva a la siguiente línea:

```js
numero = !isNaN( numero ) ? numero + 1 : 1;
```

Donde hemos utilizado un operador ternario que funciona de la siguiente manera:

```js
variable = ( condicion ) ? verdadero : falso;
```

Es decir, indicamos, que si `numero` es un número válido devuelva la expresion `numero + 1` , de lo contrario, devuelva `1`.

Después de haber validado el valor obtenido con la expresión anterior incorporaremos el valor obtenido y actualizado en la caja de texto `mostrador` , como se indica en la siguiente línea:

```js
mostrador.value = numero;
```

Answer (score 3):

Basta con que añadas un string para que JavaScript considere todo lo demás como string, por este motivo se está concatenando, debes hacer un `parseInt` para solucionarlo

```js
add1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  mostrador.value = parseInt(mostrador.value)+1;
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="mostrador">
<input type="button" value="+" id="add1"/>
```